# SQL Filter Data according to date

Tags: sql-server

I have table

```
+---------------+------------+------------+--------+
| AccountNumber |  OpenDate  | CloseDate  | Status |
+---------------+------------+------------+--------+
|          1100 | 01/01/2020 | 01/10/2020 | closed |
|          1100 | 01/01/2020 | 01/05/2020 | open   |
|          1111 | 01/02/2020 | 01/20/2020 | open   |
|          1100 | 01/01/2020 | 01/02/2020 | open   |
|          1122 | 01/08/2020 | 01/03/2020 | open   |
+---------------+------------+------------+--------+
```

The output I want is

```
+---------------+------------+------------+--------+
| AccountNumber |  OpenDate  | CloseDate  | Status |
+---------------+------------+------------+--------+
|          1111 | 01/02/2020 | 01/20/2020 |  open  |
|          1122 | 01/08/2020 | 01/03/2020 |  open  |
+---------------+------------+------------+--------+
```

I do not want accounts that are closed. Need only the open accounts in output dataset

Comment: `SELECT AccountNumber, OpenDate, CloseDate, Status FROM table_name WHERE Status = "open";` It's a common query in `mysql`. Do some more research and try yourself first! also check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What did you try? Can you format this properly, as a table, and add code you tried and why it didn't work? as mentioned, do some research first, try couple of solution and then formulate a question more precisely with the exact issue you are facing. To get better answers, loom at how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask